# what is generated and intermediates folders in build directory and why outputs folder is missing

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm building application with Android Studio and Gradle. When the build is finished the `build` folder contains the following folders:

```
- assets
- CordovaLib
  - build
  - src
  - build.gradle
- gradle
- src
  - com.my.package
    - CordovaApp
- build.gradle
- build
  - generated
  - intermediates
  - outputs        //not displayed in android studio's project tree
  - tmp            //not displayed in android studio's project tree
```

1) What are generated, intermediates and tpm folders?
2) Why aren't the outputs and tmp folder shown in studio's project tree?

Comment: What is your directory exact? `MyApplication/build` or `MyApplication/app/build` ? I not see any folder with what you named above in MyProjects directory.

Comment: I don't have `app` directory. The project tree was created by `Cordova` app. I updated my question to show almost all project tree structure. Maybe some configuration in `gradle.build` will help?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The "generated" folder contains java code generated by Android Studio for the module.  The primary file here is "R.java" which assigns symbolic names to each of the items in the "res" directory so they can be referenced in java source code.

The "intermediates" folder contains individual files that are created during the build process and which are eventually combined to produce the "apk" file.

The output folder is missing because the module ".iml" file explicitly excludes it with the following statement:

`<excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/outputs" />`

Remove that line and the "output" directory will appear under build.

Comment: Great, thanks! What about `tmp` folder? And if android by defaul hides `outputs`, maybe there is no reason to show it?

Comment: Anything to say re my previous comment? :)

Comment: should this be added to git ignore than? I guess yes

Comment: Offtopic but are "intermediates" safe to delete? Mine are taking a lot of space

Comment: you can do `gradlew clean` and intermediate folders are going bye-bye, but they will be re-generated on the next build.