# Are changes to the assets folder picked up in Android Studio incremental builds?

Tags: android, android-studio, assets

Updating a file in `/app/src/main/assets` with the same name and clicking "Run" without any other changes, but they don't seem to be picked up. Also using Device File Explorer to compare, seems to be the case...unless I'm missing something or doing something wrong here.

Asked BingChat (GPT-4) and this is what it told me, but the sources don't necessarily seem to corroborate it.

> When you make changes to the assets folder in Android Studio, these changes are not picked up in incremental builds. This is because when you pass whole directories to AAPT2 (Android Asset Packaging Tool), it recompiles all files in the directory even when only one resource has changed¹. Although you can pass resource directories containing more than one resource file to AAPT2 using the --dir flag, you don't gain the benefits of incremental resource compilation this way¹. So, if you're making changes to the assets folder and want those changes to be reflected, you'll need to do a clean build.
> Source: Conversation with Bing, 9/14/2023

> (1) AAPT2 | Android Studio | Android Developers. https://developer.android.com/tools/aapt2.
> (2) . https://bing.com/search?q=Android+Studio+incremental+builds+assets+folder+changes.
> (3) android - what is generated and intermediates folders in build .... [what is generated and intermediates folders in build directory and why outputs folder is missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27087309/what-is-generated-and-intermediates-folders-in-build-directory-and-why-outputs-f).
> (4) android - Assets folder not upgraded when installing new app - Stack .... [Assets folder not upgraded when installing new app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57476749/assets-folder-not-upgraded-when-installing-new-app).
> (5) Where to place the 'assets' folder in Android Studio?. [Where to place the 'assets' folder in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18302603/where-to-place-the-assets-folder-in-android-studio).
> (6) undefined. [Adding an assets folder in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26706843/adding-an-assets-folder-in-android-studio).
> (7) undefined. https://developer.android.com/build.

Comment: It really _should_ pick up the changes; it would be a bug if it doesn't.  (The Bing response is complete nonsense; the logic isn't even internally consistent.)  If it picks up the changes with a clean build but not an incremental build, it may be worth reporting as a bug.

Comment: After some investigation, it seems like uninstall and reinstall is required to ensure that the changes are reflected. Kind of wild.

Comment: That definitely seems like a bug.  If you can come up with a full set of steps, I'd definitely encourage you to report it (see https://source.android.com/docs/setup/contribute/report-bugs).

Comment: A bit of searching turns up [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57476749/208273) (which it looks like Bing Chat found, too) with a similar problem.  I'm not an expert on the assets folder, but having used it in the past, that's certainly not my understanding of how it's supposed to work.